# How to get the absolute path to the sites/all folder in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, relative-path, drupal-theming, absolute-path

I want to display two different logos on my drupal site: one for the front page and one for the inner pages.

```
if (drupal_is_front_page()) { 
    $variables['logo']=drupal_get_path('theme', 'hanna') . '/images/logo.png';
  } 
   else {
    $variables['logo']=drupal_get_path('theme', 'hanna') . '/images/logo-inner.png';    
  }
```

This works just fine for the front page and any page which has websiteurl/page as URL; however, it doesn't work for the pages where the URL is similar to websiteurl/custompath/page.

I think the problem lies in the relativeness of the pages which have a custom URL path.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the drupal global `$base_url` to get the absolute path of the installation and append the absolute path of your image to it.

See [the Drupal Documentation to this topic](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--globals.php/global/base_url/7).

You can also use [base_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/base_path/7) to get the path.

Comment: yea, I have used base_path().drupal_get_path('theme', 'hanna') . '/images/logo.png';

Answer (score 4):

It's important to note that:

- `base_path()` returns the relative path to the folder where your drupal website is installed.
- `$base_url` returns your domain path without a trailing slash.

So to be certain to have the right absolute path, you have to use both of them:

```
//example to get an image absolute path
global $base_url;

$image_path = $base_url . base_path() . path_to_theme() . '/images/my-image.png';
//$image_path will output something like: "http://www.my-domain.com/sites/all/themes/your-theme-name/images/my-image.png"
```

NB: `path_to_theme` is like $base_url, no trailing slash.

Comment: NOTA BENE: I found today that `path_to_theme` will return the path of where the template is defined. For exeample if the theme function is from a module, then it will return the module path and not the theme path...